# Using a RCA-to-USB capture device on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, video-conversion

I've been handed down a [Lexus](http://www.lexuselectronic.com/) UR-19 capture/converter device: It has RCA (and S-Video) inputs, connected to some dongle with a USB A male output. I'm guessing it does some sort of simplistic A/D conversion, and some piece of software on the attached CD actually puts this into a usable container.

Unfortunately, the CD is Windows-only. Can I get this to work on Linux?

I've tried looking for the product on the manufacturer's website, but it's not there. I'm also writing them, but I was unoptimistic about that. Is there something else I can do?

Note: If push comes to shove I'll get a computer with Windows installed.

Comment: If there's absolutely no drivers available, then using windows in a virtual machine might still work "in linux". But does anything show up in `dmesg` or  the syslog (usually `/var/log/syslog`) when plugging it in? Maybe you're lucky and it's already recognized & vlc might "just work" with it.

Comment: First step is to type `dmesg`, plug in the device, type `dmesg` again, and edit your question with the additional lines that appear. Next step is to google for vendor/device id in the form `xxxx:yyyy`, as shown in the above lines.

Comment: Have you tried just using multimedia software with the dongle without the driver?  The bundled driver software is sometimes generic and duplicates functionality available in the OS or built into the application software.

Comment: @fixer1234: Can you be more specific? Which app specifically?

Comment: I was thinking generically about dongles.  I buy all kinds of devices that come with a driver disk, but rarely need to load it because of the presence of generic drivers in the OS.  I don't do a lot of multimedia stuff, so I'm not up on the capabilities of the various apps.  But especially if you are using a full-featured app, I would just try it.  It's possible that you may not need the driver disk.